# Weblogic Log4j2 setup not printing Debug messages

Tags: java, weblogic, log4j2

So i have a simple properties handler java code which prints these loggers . I am using commons logging and log4j2

```
import org.apache.commons.vfs2.FileObject;
import org.apache.commons.vfs2.FileSystemException;
import org.apache.commons.vfs2.FileSystemManager;
import org.apache.commons.vfs2.VFS;
import org.apache.commons.vfs2.impl.DefaultFileMonitor;

import org.apache.commons.logging.Log; 
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;


/**
 * Provides functions to get the property file from cache or load it into cache.
 *
 */
public final class PropertiesHandler {
    
    private static final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(PropertiesHandler.class);

    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        
  logger.debug("(((((New debug logger used in Log4j2)))))");
       logger.warn("(((((New warn logger used in Log4j2)))))");
       logger.info("(((((New info logger used in Log4j2)))))");
       logger.error("(((((New error logger used in Log4j2)))))");
      logger.debug("Entering getPropertyValue");
      logger.debug("propertyKey : [" + propertyKey + "]");
      logger.debug("propertyFile : [" + propertyFile + "]");
                }

.... 
<<Some other code>>
```

which is packaged as a jar and used inside a service inside weblogic server.

my log4j2.xml which is packaged as part of the jar  looks like hthis

```
<Configuration status="error">
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="consoleLogger" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%-7p %d [%t] %c %x - %m%n" />
        </Console>
        <RollingFile name="fileLogger"
            fileName="propertieshelper.log"
            filePattern="${filename}.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}" append="true">
            <PatternLayout pattern=" %-7p %d [%t] %c %x - %m%n" />
            <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="102400KB" />
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="5" />
        </RollingFile>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
    <Logger name="ca.bell" level ="debug">
            
            <AppenderRef ref="fileLogger" />
            <AppenderRef ref="consoleLogger" />
        </Logger>

        <Root level="error">
        <AppenderRef ref="fileLogger" />
        
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

now when i run my jar as a standalone in eclipse it prints my needed loggers.

```
.
.
.

ERROR   2022-04-29 13:45:36,705 [main] ca.bell.dao.properties.handler.PropertiesHandler [] - Unable to lookup startup property appConfigPath, using propertieshelper.properties embedded in the jar
DEBUG   2022-04-29 13:45:36,712 [main] ca.bell.common.utlis.PropertiesLoader [] - Loading properties from class path : propertieshelper.properties
DEBUG   2022-04-29 13:45:36,712 [main] ca.bell.common.utlis.PropertiesLoader [] - Loading properties using input stream 
DEBUG   2022-04-29 13:45:36,713 [main] ca.bell.dao.properties.handler.PropertiesHandler [] - Derived default properties file : /opt/oracle/OSM/env.properties
DEBUG   2022-04-29 13:45:36,713 [main] ca.bell.dao.properties.handler.PropertiesHandler [] - (((((New debug logger used in Log4j2)))))
WARN    2022-04-29 13:45:36,714 [main] ca.bell.dao.properties.handler.PropertiesHandler [] - (((((New warn logger used in Log4j2)))))
INFO    2022-04-29 13:45:36,714 [main] ca.bell.dao.properties.handler.PropertiesHandler [] - (((((New info logger used in Log4j2)))))
ERROR   2022-04-29 13:45:36,714 [main] ca.bell.dao.properties.handler.PropertiesHandler [] - (((((New error logger used in Log4j2)))))
DEBUG   2022-04-29 13:45:36,714 [main] ca.bell.dao.properties.handler.PropertiesHandler [] - Entering getPropertyValue
DEBUG   2022-04-29 13:45:36,718 [main] ca.bell.dao.properties.handler.PropertiesHandler [] - propertyKey : [text]
DEBUG   2022-04-29 13:45:36,718 [main] ca.bell.dao.properties.handler.PropertiesHandler [
.
.
.
```

but when i use this jar within my service and deploy the app to weblogic jar it does NOT print the "debug" logs ONLY.  it does Prints the rest. So what am i doing wrong ?

--
server side logs for this properties handler app

```
.
.
.
5:19 AM EDT> <Warning> <ca.bell.dao.properties.handler.PropertiesHandler> <BEA-000000> <(((((New warn logger used in Log4j2)))))>
<Apr 29, 2022 3:15:19 AM EDT> <Info> <ca.bell.dao.properties.handler.PropertiesHandler> <BEA-000000> <(((((New info logger used in Log4j2)))))>
<Apr 29, 2022 3:15:19 AM EDT> <Error> <ca.bell.dao.properties.handler.PropertiesHandler> <BEA-000000> <(((((New error logger used in Log4j2)))))>
<Apr 29, 2022 3:15:19 AM EDT> <Warning> <ca.bell.dao.properties.handler.PropertiesHandler> <BEA-000000> <(((((New warn logger used in Log4j2)))))>
<Apr 29, 2022 3:15:19 AM EDT> <Info> <ca.bell.dao.properties.handler.PropertiesHandler> <BEA-000000> <(((((New info logger used in Log4j2)))))>
<Apr 29, 2022 3:15:19 AM EDT> <Error> <ca.bell.dao.properties.handler.PropertiesHandler> <BEA-000000> <(((((New error logger used in Log4j2)))))>
.
.
.
```